# subreddit image bot

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, reddit

I wrote a bot in python 3 using PRAW, requests, and BeautifulSoup that downloads a specified amount of image posts from a specified subreddit.

One limitation is that it can only parse the direct image link from imgur pages, but I am not too bent on figuring them out because the majority of image posts on reddit are from imgur, and I don't care about skipping a few submissions.

Any suggestions on how I could improve this code? Any glaring issues? I am new to web scraping so I am not sure on how things can break.

```
import io
import os
import zipfile

import praw
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

DOWNLOAD_PATH = '.'


def is_direct_image(url):
    """Checks if a url is a direct image url by checking
    if the url contains a file extension. Only checks
    for png, gif, jpg, and jpeg, as these are the only
    formats we are likely to encounter.
    """
    return any(ex in url.lower() for ex in ['.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg'])


def get_image_url(url):
    """Returns direct image url from imgur page."""
    req = requests.get(url)
    req.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    img = soup.find('img', class_='post-image-placeholder')
    try:
        return f'http:{img.get("src")}'
    except AttributeError:
        print(f'Encountered unsupported url: {url}')


def download_image(url, path=DOWNLOAD_PATH, chunksize=512):
    """Downloads each image to the specified download path.
    Uses the image ID as the filename.
    """
    req = requests.get(url)
    req.raise_for_status()
    filename = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in req.iter_content(chunksize):
            file.write(chunk)


def download_album(url, path=DOWNLOAD_PATH, max_size=26214400):
    """Downloads an album from imgur as a zip file and extracts it."""
    req = requests.get(f'{url}/zip', stream=True)
    req.raise_for_status()
    filesize = int(req.headers['Content-Length'])
    if filesize > max_size:
        req.close()
        return None
    with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(req.content)) as file:
        file.extractall(path)


def download_from_subreddit(sub='wallpapers', sort='hot', lim=10, albums=True,
                            path=DOWNLOAD_PATH):
    """Downloads images from specifed subreddit."""
    reddit = praw.Reddit('bot1')
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(sub)
    subreddit_sort = {
        'hot': subreddit.hot,
        'top': subreddit.top,
        'new': subreddit.new
    }

    for submission in subreddit_sort[sort](limit=lim):
        # skip stickied and self posts
        if submission.stickied or submission.is_self:
            continue
        url = submission.url
        if '/a/' in url and albums:
            download_album(url, path=path)
        else:
            if not is_direct_image(url):
                url = get_image_url(url)
            if url is not None:
                download_image(url, path=path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    download_from_subreddit()
```

Answer (score 2):

- As you're on Python 3.6+, you should definitely use [function annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) and [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) to make your code more understandable to others.
- `any(ex in url.lower() for ex in ['.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg'])` can be replaced with `url.lower().endswith(('.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))`. Another option is to use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module and do: `Path(url).suffix in {'.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg'}`.
- Similarly `filename = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]` can be replaced with `filename = Path(url).name`.
- If we replace `DOWNLOAD_PATH = '.'` with `DOWNLOAD_PATH = Path('.')` then `os.path.join(path, filename)` can be changed to `path.joinpath(filename)`.
- Group `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` with other 3rd part imports.
- The variable name `req` in `req = requests.get(f'{url}/zip', stream=True)` is misleading as it is actually a response object, the request object can be obtained using `req.request`.
- Instead of closing the response explicitly you could use [`with statement`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow): 
  `with requests.get(f'{url}/zip', stream=True) as response:`
- Use [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to re-use connections and improve performance.

---

Don't do too many things that are tightly coupled to each other in a single function, instead break them into multiple function calls so that each of them can be isolated and can be tested or mocked easily. For example `get_image_url` currently fetched the HTML content and then it is parsed. We can break it into two different functions: `get_url_content` and `parse_content`. Now `get_url_content` can be used anywhere where we want the content of page and `parse_content` can accept any content for parsing and return a URL. This can be done with other functions as well for example getting `subreddit_sort` can be a separate function etc

Comment: I followed your advice in splitting up logic a bit more, but on using session, what connections am I reusing? Is accessing any page on the same domain reusing a connection? Would it work by making a session object on a module level and passing it to the function as an argument/using it directly?

Comment: @EpicNice Use a module level session. Yes, connections to the same hosts are re-used.